# What are these black spots near my dog’s anus?

Tags: dogs, skin-condition

I have a 3yr old French Bulldog that has developed little black slots on the upper left side of her anus, right underneath her tail nubbin. They don’t dislodge when I scrub them in a bath. They don’t really match what I see when searching anal gland problems, so I’m uncertain what they are or if I need to seek medical attention.

Can anyone help me determine what is causing these?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did she have scabbing of any sort at some point? My dog had the same sort of discolouration after some scabs heales.

Comment: No scabbing. And it doesn’t appear to bother her at all (not scratching the site, or rubbing on the carpet or anything)

Comment: It kind of looks like hyperpigmentation https://betterpet.com/hyperpigmentation-in-dogs/, which could be caused by a number of things.  Though I think the spots may be a little small for that (I'm no vet, so I can't say if size really matters or not for this ailment).

Comment: If the dog isn't showing discomfort and otherwise seems healthy, I'd wait and ask the vet at the next appointment. But If you're worried, it's entirely reasonable to schedule an appointment sooner -- or ask the vet whether this sounds like something they should look at. Or, if the vet has email, send them the pics and ask if you should bring the pup in. Part of a vet's job is calming pet owners..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vet confirmed there are basically acne blackheads (comedones). Since they don't appear to bother my dog, and they aren't infected, they basically are just a cosmetic issue.  Vet said that while she would normally suggest an acne pad like [Stridex](https://stridex.com/), given the sensitivity of the skin in that area, she said she would actually not suggest that for my dog unless they started to become problematic.